# Can anyone provide a list of VLC hot keys

Tags: keyboard, vlc-media-player, shortcuts

Can anyone provide a list of keyboard / mouse shortcuts available for VLC ?
Such as <kbd>F</kbd> for Fullscreen view.

Comment: They are customizable, so if you want defaults, check the page that Joe linked to. If you want to see what yours currently are, check the preferences page that A.L. mentioned.

Answer (score 5):

1. start vlc
2. main menu -> tools -> preferences -> hotkeys

tested with vlc 1.1.13 on linux

Answer (score 3):

Taken from [here](http://www.shortcutworld.com/en/win/VLC-Media-Player_1.html):

1. #### Most used

   - <kbd>f</kbd> = Fullscreen
   - <kbd>Space</kbd> = Pause or play movie
   - <kbd>v</kbd> = Subtitles cylce/off
   - <kbd>b</kbd> = Audio track cycle
   - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd> = Volume
2. #### Mouse actions

   - <kbd>Double click</kbd> = Fullscreen
   - <kbd>Scroll</kbd> = Volume or Position (see settings)
   - <kbd>Right click</kbd> = Local menu (play controls, audio/video)
3. #### Movie Navigation

   - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> = Open disc menu
   - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> = Open folder (browse folder menu)
   - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> = Advanced open file
   - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> = Open single file(s)
   - <kbd>m</kbd> = Mute and unmute audio
   - <kbd>p</kbd> = Play movie (from the very beginning)
   - <kbd>s</kbd> = Stop movie
   - <kbd>Esc</kbd> = Exit full screen mode
   - <kbd>[</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>/<kbd>-</kbd>/<kbd>=</kbd> = Faster, slower, normal
   - <kbd>a</kbd> = Aspect ratio
   - <kbd>c</kbd> = Crop screen
   - <kbd>g</kbd>/<kbd>h</kbd> = Decrease subtitle delay / Increase subtitle delay
   - <kbd>j</kbd>/<kbd>k</kbd> = Decrease audio delay / Increase audio delay
   - <kbd>z</kbd> = Change zoom mode
   - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> = Recent media (in Media - Recent media menu)
   - <kbd>t</kbd> = Show time
   - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> = Goto time
4. #### Jump in playback

   - <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd> = Very short jump (3 seconds)
   - <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd> = Short jump (10 seconds)
   - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd> = Medium jump (1 minute)
   - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd> = Long jump
5. #### Manage VLC, Playlists, and Special Commands

   - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> = Hide / unhide controls
   - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> = Preferences/ interface settings
   - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> = Adjustments and audio/video effects
   - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> = Edit bookmarks
   - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd> = Open messages
   - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> = Open network
   - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> = Open captue device
   - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd> = Open playlist
   - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>y</kbd> = Save playlist
   - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> = Media information
   - <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> = Open audio menu
   - <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> = Open help menu
   - <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd> = Open media menu
   - <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> = Open playlist menu
   - <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> = Open tool menu
   - <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> = Open video menu
   - <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd> = Open playback menu
   - <kbd>D</kbd> = Show movie path
   - <kbd>n</kbd> = Play next movie from playlist
   - <kbd>F1</kbd> = Show Help
   - <kbd>F11</kbd> = Window full-screen (not equal to pressing F)
   - <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd> = Quit VLC

Comment: `shift-v` to toggle subtitles